# css psuedo elements manipulation by vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, css

i was trying to make my portfolio website with vanilla javascript. it's not half way there yet, i am facing some issues with the sidebar content. i've made the sidebar contents with (triangle top left) shape at the end, below is the html file ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Document</title>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="section">
            <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="image" class="avatar" />
            <p class="text-center">
                Hello World !
            </p>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JS -->
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/tooltip.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the css file ->

```
.avatar {
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.section {
    margin-left: -400px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.content {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: -400px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.content:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    top: -4px;
    border-top: 50px solid rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

and the js file ->

```
var section = document.querySelectorAll("div.section");
section[0].style.marginLeft = "0px";
section[0].style.transition = 0.5 + "s";

var content = document.querySelectorAll("div.content");

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        content[i].style.marginLeft = "0px";
        content[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4)";
        content[i].style.transition = (i + 1) * 0.2 + "s";
        content[i].style.transitionDelay = "0.5s";
    }
});

for (let j = 0; j < content.length; j++) {
    content[j].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        content[j].style.width = "300px";
        content[j].style.transition = ".5s";
        content[j].style.transitionDelay = "0s";
        // window.getComputedStyle(content[j], ":after").getPropertyValue("left");
    });
    content[j].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        content[j].style.width = "250px";
        content[j].style.transition = ".5s";
        content[j].style.transitionDelay = "0s";
    });
}
```

everything seems to be ok but, when i am adding hover effect, the shapes overlaps with the div. it's because i am using (:after) css pseudo element. i've managed to access the pseudo element's value in javascript by `window.getComputedStyle(content[j], ":after").getPropertyValue("left");` it's returning the pseudo elements value, when console.log() it. but how can i change the value and add more styles like change colors to it while hovering ?

Comment: No need to use javascript you can use css and update .content:hover:after

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333

Comment: ok, your solution works. thanks for that. but after adding .content:hover:after {
    left: 175px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}, when i mouse out the overlap effect is there, and how to fix that ? @Casper